# How to know all roles a user has in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I use Spring security so log in on the site I'm building to study Spring. I used Hibernate to map User object to other objects that allow user to see or not pages, according to its role. It works.

I was asking if I can know by using **authorities-by-username-query**, all the role a single user has, instead of checking my User object.
This is my query:

```
        authorities-by-username-query="select u1.utente, 
        u1.email, u2.descrizione, u3.id_autorizzazioni,
        u3.autorizzazione from autenticazione u1,
        autorizzazione u2, autorizzazioni
        u3 where u1.utente = u3.utente and 
        u2.id_autorizzazione = u3.autorizzazione and u1.email =?"
```

If I write that query on mysql console I get 3 records, so the query it's right.

This is my database

[image]

I used
`Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();`
but I always get a collection that have size 1 instead of 3 (I have 3 roles in the db for the user, as you can see in the pic). I don't understand if it depends on my db or my **authorities-by-username-query**. Probably one of the two things is wrong

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I know all the rolesof a user

Comment: What role do you get in the 1-size Collection?

Comment: Thanks everybody. The problem was  the authorities-by-username-query query. As second field of the query I should retrieve the ROLES. So far I got just one element, because i was getting the email of the user logged, according to the wrong query I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()` to obtain a collection of the currently logged in user's roles.

```
Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
```

You have the collection of roles in the authorities variable.

Little  bit more excercise

```
private boolean hasRole(String role) {
  Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<GrantedAuthority>)
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
  boolean hasRole = false;
  for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
     hasRole = authority.getAuthority().equals(role);
     if (hasRole) {
      break;
     }
  }
  return hasRole;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried using it, but i always get a collection that have size 1 instead of 3 (i have 3 roles in the db for the user). I don't understand if it depends on my db or my query. Probably one of the two things is wrong

Comment: Thanks everybody. The problem was  the authorities-by-username-query query. As second field of the query I should retrieve the ROLES. So far I got just one element, because i was getting the email of the user logged, according to the wrong query I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different approaches:

- query for the user roles (of any user) in the database
- "look" in the Session to get the roles of the current user

For the first approach it is possible to invoke the `UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(String username)` method.

For the second approach: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();`

Comment: I don't want to make another query, i'm wondering if I can use "authorities-by-username-query". What you mean with "look in the Session"?. I'm able to know the username, but I couldn't find a way to know the list of the roles

Comment: `UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername` reuse the query!

Comment: Thanks everybody. The problem was  the authorities-by-username-query query. As second field of the query I should retrieve the ROLES. So far I got just one element, because i was getting the email of the user logged, according to the wrong query I wrote.